# Problems accessing list objects by index as returned by Django ORM manager (objects.all())

Tags: django

I have two classes, with a one-to-many relationship between them.

I have a test running that results in the parent object ('fm') containing two child objects, accessible through the relevant manager ('changelog').

The following code runs, indicating that the 'changelog' list contains two distinct `UserMessageStatusUpdate` objects, with different properties:

```
>>> logging.debug(fm.changelog.all())
DEBUG [<UserMessageStatusUpdate: fred changed message status from New to Received>,
    <UserMessageStatusUpdate: fred changed message status from Received to Read>]
```

I can also loop through them:

```
>>> for m in fm.changelog.all():
    ....logging.debug(m)
DEBUG fred changed message status from New to Received
DEBUG fred changed message status from Received to Read
```

However, if I try and access each object by its index, I get something else altogether:

```
>>> logging.debug(fm.changelog.all()[0])
DEBUG fred changed message status from Received to Read
>>> logging.debug(fm.changelog.all()[1])
DEBUG fred changed message status from Received to Read
```

What on earth is going on here?

[UPDATE 1]

I have added the ID to the model _str_() method, and so now I can see that the access by index method is returning the same record twice:

```
>>> logging.debug(fm.changelog.all()[0])
DEBUG id:3 fred changed message status from Received to Read
>>> logging.debug(fm.changelog.all()[1])
DEBUG id:3 fred changed message status from Received to Read
```

So now the question is why is the manager returning the same record when accessing via the index? (It's the default `Manager`, nothing fancy.)

[UPDATE 2]

Investigating this with @stevejalim, the tests will pass if the `fm.changelog.all()` object is explicitly case to a `list`:

```
>>> changelog = list(fm.changelog.all())
>>> logging.debug(changelog[0])
DEBUG id:2 fred changed message status from New to Received
>>> logging.debug(changelog[1])
DEBUG id:3 fred changed message status from Received to Read
```

Looking at fm.changelog.all():

```
>>> logging.debug(type(fm.changelog.all()))
DEBUG <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
```

Seems like the issue may have been related to the QuerySet returning a Generator, and being unable to access items directly by index. Or possibly related to this line in the `RelatedManager` class: https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L458

```
def get_query_set(self):
    try:
        return self.instance._prefetched_objects_cache[rel_field.related_query_name()]
```

Basically, it's a mystery, but casting to a list does the job.1

Comment: What happens if you assign the queryset to a variable once, then acccess it by index?

Comment: Why don't we go step by step..let's start by printing the contents of fm.changelog.all() only and show us the implementation of changelog

Comment: That's precisely what I've done above. Printed the list, looped through the list and then accessed the list by index. What I've shown above is a subset of all the debugging I've done to date. I'm really looking for anyone who has experienced this behaviour before, not assistance in debugging it further.

Comment: Is there an generator at work here (ie, a queryset.iterator()) instead of a standard queryset list?

Comment: Seems like that may be it - as explicitly casting to a list solves the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the solution to this was to cast the QuerySet returned as a list. I strongly suspect that this is a bug in the underlying django implementation, as it's unexpected behaviour to return the wrong element when accessing via index, but I can't work out exactly where it's going wrong.

Default behaviour gives the wrong (unexpected) result:

```
>>> changelog = fm.changelog.all()
>>> changelog[0]
id:3 fred changed message status from Received to Read
>>> changelog[1]
id:3 fred changed message status from Received to Read
```

Casting to a list gives the correct (expected) result:

```
>>> changelog = list(fm.changelog.all())
>>> changelog[0]
id:2 fred changed message status from New to Received
>>> changelog[1]
id:3 fred changed message status from Received to Read
```